# unit testing a TabbedPropertySection

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, tdd, legacy-code

I am trying to unit test a class which extends org.eclipse.ui.views.properties.tabbed.AbstractPropertySection
It is a GUI on top of a heap of legacy code. The AbstractPropertySection class have a

```
private TabbedPropertySheetPage tabbedPropertySheetPage;
```

field, which is initialized by its

```
public void createControls(Composite parent,
        TabbedPropertySheetPage aTabbedPropertySheetPage)
```

method, and used by its

```
public TabbedPropertySheetWidgetFactory getWidgetFactory();
```

method, which in turn used by widget creation. I cannot mock it up in a way that creating a Button would actually create one. As it is both legacy and GUI, maybe it would be wiser to use the Real Thing? But how?

I am doing basically this:

```
            private LineDecorationSection section;
            private DiagramConnectionMockup data;
            //contains both the model object and editPart
            data = new DiagramConnectionMockup();
            ConnectionDecorationFactory.getInstance();
            //a descendant of the class to be tested,
            //augmented with methods to handle what would be done and seen
            //on the GUI
            section = new LineDecorationSectionExerciser();
            assertTrue(section instanceof LineDecorationSection);
            //a selection containing theeditPart
            ISelection selection = new SelectionMockup(data.getEditPart());
            //an editor (Legacy)
            IWorkbenchPart editor = new ZentaDiagramEditor(); 
            section.setInput(editor, selection);

            //------------This fails-----------
            assertNotNull(section.getWidgetFactory()); 

            LineDecorationSectionExerciser exerciser = (LineDecorationSectionExerciser)section;
            Button but = ((Button)exerciser.getInternal("DefaultButton"));

            //----and this prints "but=null"------------
            System.out.println("but="+but);
            but.setSelection(true);
```

The actual code is here: https://github.com/magwas/zenta/blob/001f83c8951a4840b84cd1ff402baa5b96feb4e5/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.editor/src/org/rulez/magwas/zenta/tests/propertysections/LineDecorationSectionTest.java

Question: what to add to the unit tests and mockups so that the unit tests run, and widgets get created?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have come up with real underlying data and mockups for the Property Sheet page and the goo coming with it. Maybe not the best solution, but I have put the mockup initialisation into the exerciser class.
The solution for the real-world problem is here:

https://github.com/magwas/zenta/blob/51fd9f6b9e363eb5967a3d24b22d012b5bdd6492/org.rulez.magwas.zenta.editor/src/org/rulez/magwas/zenta/tests/propertysections/LineDecorationSectionTest.java